# Why do struct declarations sometimes contain blank fields?

Tags: go

From the [golang spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types)

```
// A struct with 6 fields.
struct {
    x, y int
    u float32
    _ float32  // padding
    A *[]int
    F func()
}
```

- Are there any practical scenarios of using the **blank** `_` fields inside a `struct`? (some code snippets would be appreciated)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  The type definition seems to compile okay for me.  e.g. http://play.golang.org/p/2MPeKFOoZ-

Comment: @JamesHenstridge quesion updated, I was declaring it in the top-level (outside of any function)

Comment: I think you'd need it if a C library, syscall, SSE/AVX instruction, or other low-level thing that you can call out to expects something to have a particular memory layout or alignment. I don't usually work on that kind of thing (and the one time I did it was in C++, not Go), so I don't have good examples or know more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The padding is exactly what it is called: Some padding to align the following field to your needs, e.g. to match the layout of a C struct. It cannot be accessed (at least not without package unsafe).